# Electron app executable keeps opening many application tasks

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron, electron-builder

I developed an application using Electron and React and I built it using [electron builder](https://www.electron.build/). When I run the generated executable, it opens a lot of task of the same application, as if I clicked to open it many times.

I recorded it: https://streamable.com/rj4w32

Notes:

- The tasks keep starting forever until my computer run out of memory or I shut it down
- I can close the apps but they keep opening over and over
- The same thing happens if I run the linux-unpacked executable
- **It doesn't happen if I run it on development enviroment with `npm run dev`**
- npm run dev: `"concurrently -k \"BROWSER=none npm start\" \"npm:electron\""`
- Building command: `"electron:build": "npm run build && electron-builder -c.extraMetadata.main=build/main.js"`
- OS: Zorin OS 16
- Electron Builder version: 22.14.5
- Electron version: 16.0.6

My **public/main.js**:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu, MenuItem } = require('electron');

const isDev = require('electron-is-dev');
const menu = require('./scripts/menu.js');

require("./scripts/ipcCalls.js");

let win;

function createWindow() {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1280,
    height: 720,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
      contextIsolation: false
    },
  });

  win.loadURL(
    isDev
      ? 'http://localhost:3000'
      : `file://${path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html')}`
  );
}

if (isDev){
  menu.append(new MenuItem({
    label: 'Dev',
    submenu: [{
      role: 'Reload',
      accelerator: process.platform === 'darwin' ? 'Cmd+R' : 'Ctrl+R',
      click: () => { win.reload(); }
    }, {
      role: 'ForceReload',
      accelerator: process.platform === 'darwin' ? 'Cmd+Shift+R' : 'Ctrl+Shift+R',
      click: () => { win.webContents.reloadIgnoringCache(); }
    }, {
      type: 'separator'
    }, {
      label: 'Open DevTools',
      accelerator: process.platform === 'darwin' ? 'Cmd+Shift+I' : 'Ctrl+Shift+I',
      click: () => { win.webContents.openDevTools({ mode: 'detach' }); }
    }]
  }));
}

Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);

app.whenReady().then(createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

EDIT: I noticed that in my Task Manager there is a process called `snarf-0.1.0.AppImage` and when I kill it all the tasks get killed as well and they stop appearing

Comment: Running the linux-unpacked + task manager: https://streamable.com/g3h3aq

Comment: I know you see many tasks, but did you make sure this code `if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) { createWindow(); }` is not being executed over and over again? Debug this part. Or just comment out this part and see if it makes any difference. This line `app.whenReady().then(createWindow);` should already create the initial window.

Comment: @Ma3x You are right, this `if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) { createWindow(); }` makes no sense at all, I commented it out and built it again, but the results were just the same. 
Just to make sure, I un-commented it and instead I commented `app.whenReady().then(createWindows);` instead, this time it started many background processes but no window (as expected).
But I noticed that there's in my task manager there is a process called `snarf-0.1.0.AppImage` and if I kill it the tasks stop spawning